# i am trying to print calling function in javascript code but at the same time i am getting undefined.here is the code

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function myFunction() 
{

 document.write("calling function")
   }
 document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=myFunction();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

function myFunction() { document.write("calling function") } document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=myFunction();

Answer (score 1):

The function writes "calling function" on the page, but it returns nothing. Hence

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=myFunction();
```

this statement returns undefined to the innerHTML